# Python Tkinter deleting entry in function

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to make an app to show the time in different time zones. I've tried to make messagebox errors for if the entry is not in pytz.all_timezones and also if the user has entered something which doesn't contain a comma. The app seems to work until I begin to delete the entry, and it comes up with a messagebox which I don't want. Also, how can I let the time be unaffected by the entry changing until I press the search button again, because as soon as I begin to delete the entry the time stops updating.

Thanks

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
import time

root=tk.Tk()
root.title('Time app')


def times():
    a = entry_1.get()

    try:

        b = a.index(',')
        c = a[b + 2:] + '/' + a[:b]

        if c in pytz.all_timezones:
            home = pytz.timezone(c)
            local_time = datetime.now(home)
            current_time = local_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

            place_lbl = Label(root, text=a, bg='grey', width=15, font=('bold', 25))
            place_lbl.place(relx=0.33, rely=0.4)
            time_lbl = Label(root, text=current_time, bg='grey', font=('bold', 30))
            time_lbl.place(relx=0.41, rely=0.5)
            time_lbl.after(200,times)
           

        else:
            messagebox.showerror('Error',"Cannot find '{}'. Please enter in form city, continent (e.g. London, Europe).".format(a))


    except:
        messagebox.showerror('Error',"Cannot find '{}'. Please enter in form city, continent (e.g. London, Europe).".format(a))

    entry_1.delete(first=0, last=20)


canvas=tk.Canvas(root,height=400,width=700,bg='grey')
canvas.grid()

header_lbl=Label(root,text='Enter a city: ',bg='grey',fg='black',font=('bold',25))
header_lbl.place(relx=0.41,rely=0.1)

entry_1=Entry(root)
entry_1.place(relx=0.37,rely=0.2)

search_btn=Button(root,text='Search',command=times)
search_btn.place(relx=0.47,rely=0.3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The reason why `except` block gets executed is that `b = a.index(',')` returns a `ValueError`

Comment: Ive added an answer, do let me know

Comment: That is brilliant thanks so much for the great explanation, it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I fixed this issue, there might be some other way too.

```
def value():
    global a
    a = entry_1.get()

def times():
    try:
        b = a.index(',')
        c = a[b + 2:] + '/' + a[:b]
        if c in pytz.all_timezones:
            home = pytz.timezone(c)
            local_time = datetime.now(home)
            current_time = local_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

            place_lbl = Label(root, text=a, bg='grey', width=15, font=('bold', 25))
            place_lbl.place(relx=0.33, rely=0.4)
            time_lbl = Label(root, text=current_time, bg='grey', font=('bold', 30))
            time_lbl.place(relx=0.41, rely=0.5)
            time_lbl.after(1000,times)
        else:
            messagebox.showerror('Error',"Cannot find '{}'. Please enter in form city, continent (e.g. London, Europe).".format(a))
    except:
        messagebox.showerror('Error',"Cannot find '{}'. Please enter in form city, continent (e.g. London, Europe).".format(a))
```

Make sure to change your button to:

```
search_btn = Button(root,text='Search',command=lambda:[value(),times(),entry_1.delete(0, END)])
```

The problem is that your using `after()` but once the code is run, the entry box is empty and then onward you will be using the deleted value inside the box. So I passed in the value initially to another function, so that it will get stored there.

With the command of the button, I'm calling in three functions, first one is the `value()` which will have the value from the entry widget, then `times()` and the next is the deletion of the entry widget. If you include the deletion inside the `times()` then it would cause the entry to be deleted each second.

This works when you want to search more cities too.